# How to download all files from an FTP directory?

Tags: ftp, wget

I am not experienced in unix or downloading files from FTP, html etc. so haven't been sure if I can safely use some other examples/questions given here.

I am looking to download files from an ftp directory into my server, with getting all the files in an ftp directory (but not downloading any other parent directory files, just the ones at this ftp: ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/opentargets/genetics/190505/sa/molecular_trait/)

From what I found I think this will work but I'm not sure:

```
wget -r -np -nd ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/opentargets/genetics/190505/sa/molecular_trait/
```

Am I along the right lines or should I be using other - arguments? I have also seen `lftp` can be used but I am unsure how to use that either.

Comment: Are you sure you want `-nd`? The remote directory structure below that directory will be lost.

Comment: As long as I get the files listed in ```/molecular_trait/``` that's all I need, but do you mean with ```-nd``` I wouldn't get those at all either? Also, there shouldn't be a directory within/beyond that and I wouldn't need it. Sorry for a basic question, I don't know what I'm doing with this so don't want to start a download of so many files to find it's wrong or I don't know how to properly cancel it.

Comment: Then it is safer to remove `-nd` from the command, that way possible directories will be saved.

Comment: Well, I don't see any directories in there, so as long as they don't add any later, it should be fine.